# Python 3 fileinput: Both compressed and endcoded filehooks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to both uncompress and decode a set of gzipped files, and the filehook module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) has hooks to both, but I am unable to apply both:

Is there a syntax to apply both of these hooks onto the same FileInput instance?

```
fi = fileinput.FileInput(openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed)
fi = fileinput.FileInput(openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("iso-8859-1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to combine these. You cannot even use `hook_compressed` with the default `utf8` by passing text mode, because `FileInput` refuses to accept `rt` on the assumption that `r` always means text.

The only solution is to write your own.

```
def hook_compressed_encoded(encoding):
    def hook(filename, mode):
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if ext == '.gz':
            import gzip
            return gzip.open(filename, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
        elif ext == '.bz2':
            import bz2
            return bz2.open(filename, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
        else:
            return open(filename, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
    return hook

fi = fileinput.FileInput(openhook=hook_compressed_encoded('iso-8859-1'))
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer because the other version raises the `ValueError` you mentioned.  However, I would suggest using the passed-in `mode` instead of `'rt'` in the uncompressed case.

Comment: @HuwWalters if you're using an encoding it has to be text mode. It's inconsistent, and not useful, to differ in the uncompressed case.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/fileinput.py#l389) and noting that [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) and [`bz2.open`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bz2.html#bz2.open) support encoding parameters, it shouldn't be too difficult to roll your own:

```
def hook_compressed_encoded(encoding):
    def hook_compressed(filename, mode):
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if ext == '.gz':
            import gzip
            return gzip.open(filename, mode, encoding=encoding)
        elif ext == '.bz2':
            import bz2
            return bz2.open(filename, mode, encoding=encoding)
        else:
            return open(filename, mode, encoding=encoding)
    return hook_compressed

fi = fileinput.FileInput(openhook=hook_compressed_encoded('iso-8859-1'))
```

Comment: ValueError: Argument 'encoding' not supported in binary mode